# Creating a new camera stream

Tags: c#, comparative-review, winforms

I'm currently in the process of refactoring some code and I was wondering if I should use `switch` or `if-else` for the is code:

**Switch**

```
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                CameraStream stream = null;
                var id = (Guid)CameraGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                var Camerasettings = Settings.GetCameraSettings(id);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, new List<PictureBox> { Camera1a, Camera1b }, 
                                                                  new List<Label> { Camera1aLbl, Camera1bLbl });
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, new List<PictureBox> { Camera2a, Camera2b },
                                                                  new List<Label> { Camera2aLbl, Camera2bLbl });
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, new List<PictureBox> { Camera3a, Camera3b },
                                                                 new List<Label> { Camera3aLbl, Camera3bLbl });
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, new List<PictureBox> { Camera4a, Camera4b },
                                                                 new List<Label> { Camera4aLbl, Camera4bLbl });
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera5, Camera5Lbl);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera6, Camera6Lbl);
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera7, Camera7Lbl);
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera8, Camera8Lbl);
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera9, Camera9Lbl);
                        break;
                }
                cameraStreams.Add(stream);
                stream.Start();
            }
```

**if**

```
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                CameraStream stream = null;
                var id = (Guid)CameraGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                var Camerasettings = Settings.GetCameraSettings(id);
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    var PicBoxes = new List<PictureBox> { Camera1a, Camera1b };
                    var Labels = new List<Label> { Camera1aLbl, Camera1bLbl };
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, PicBoxes, Labels);
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    var PicBoxes = new List<PictureBox> { Camera2a, Camera2b };
                    var Labels = new List<Label> { Camera2aLbl, Camera2bLbl };
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, PicBoxes, Labels);
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    var PicBoxes = new List<PictureBox> { Camera3a, Camera3b };
                    var Labels = new List<Label> { Camera3aLbl, Camera3bLbl };
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, PicBoxes, Labels);
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    var PicBoxes = new List<PictureBox> { Camera4a, Camera4b };
                    var Labels = new List<Label> { Camera4aLbl, Camera4bLbl };
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, PicBoxes, Labels);
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera5, Camera5Lbl);
                }
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera6, Camera6Lbl);
                }
                if (i == 6)
                {
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera7, Camera7Lbl);
                }
                if (i == 7)
                {
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera8, Camera8Lbl);
                }
                if (i == 8)
                {
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, Camera9, Camera9Lbl);
                }
                cameraStreams.Add(stream);
                stream.Start();
            }
```

Comment: remove the forloop and use if statements looks better to me.

Comment: I'm afraid neither version looks clean or maintainable. Proper refactoring in this case should go deeper than choosing between a wall of ifs and a wall of switch-cases.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I'm using WinForms

Comment: I'd put those picture boxes and labels into arrays (or arrays of arrays), so you don't need any checks and duplicated code inside your for loop. Alternately, write a utility method to simplify the creation, adding and starting of a single`CameraStream` and just call it 8 times in a row: no loop or checks needed.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet you main something like this? http://pastebin.com/JCeQnNUk

Comment: That's what I meant, yes. I'd use arrays - lists imply that items can be added at run-time, which doesn't seem likely here. You may also want to ensure that `length` doesn't exceed the length of those picture box/label arrays. And if there are other methods that use these picture boxes and labels, you could store them in a field, so they only need to be created once.

Comment: I agree with @KonradMorawski. Take a look at all the answers of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126409/ways-to-eliminate-switch-in-code) and loot it's knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your names are meaningless: `Camera1a`, `Camera1aLbl`, etc. barely inform us what they are.

---

Is there a reason why `CameraStream` has two different constructors? Why not simply have a single one which takes `Camerasettings`, `List<PictureBox>` and `List<Label>`, that way you can concentrate on filling `List<PictureBox>` and `List<Label>` and just have a single `new CameraStream()` at the end.

---

But I fear your refactoring might need to widen its scope, because even if you apply this you still have an ugly `if` or `switch`.

Answer (score -1):

what about this?

```
                CameraStream stream = null;
                var id = (Guid)CameraGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                var Camerasettings = Settings.GetCameraSettings(id);
                if (length <= 0)
                {
                    var PicBoxes = new List<PictureBox> { Camera1a, Camera1b };
                    var Labels = new List<Label> { Camera1aLbl, Camera1bLbl };
                    var stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, PicBoxes, Labels);
                     cameraStreams.Add(stream);
                     stream.Start();

                }
                if (length <= 1)
                {
                    var PicBoxes = new List<PictureBox> { Camera2a, Camera2b };
                    var Labels = new List<Label> { Camera2aLbl, Camera2bLbl };
                    stream = new CameraStream(Camerasettings, PicBoxes, Labels);
                     cameraStreams.Add(stream);
                     stream.Start();
                } ...
```

This way you remove the loop but keep the functionality, am i correct?

you can encapsulate the double code in a function with input of camera and camera label.